# I not found Gnome 3 TaskBar Extention Settings

Tags: gnome, debian, taskbar

i use debian and gnome
i add taskbar extention.I setted my taskbar previously .But i not found now.

i want found this panel
https://extensions.gnome.org/static/extension-data/screenshots/screenshot_584_23.png

Comment: Could you make this clearer as to what you want? If you right click on the Show Desktop icon the settings should load, and then you can configure it easily.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the settings for the [Taskbar extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/584/taskbar/) by right-clicking on the 'Show Desktop' icon, or by clicking on the preferences icon in [gnome-tweak-tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-tweak-tool/):

[image]

If you need to install `gnome-tweak-tool`, you can do it by running this as root:

```
apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Another way is to click thesettings icon on the [extension's page](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/584/taskbar/):

[image]